# Why am i getting Access to XMLHttpRequest denied due to cors policy in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors

I am using reactjs as frontend ad nodejs as backend. I have posted data from frontend to backend and saved it in database. But when i try t get the data in frontend using axios it gives me "Access to XMLHttpRequest at"link" denied dur to cors policy". I have installed cors and using it as

```
app.use(cors())
app.use('/api/room', route) //using route
```

My frontEnd:

```
useEffect(()=>{
const getData=()=>{
const data= await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/room')  //access denied error
}
getData()
})
```

my backend

```
route.get('/', async(req, res)=>{
    const product= await Roomdata.find({})
    res.json({message: product})
})
```

"http://localhost:8000/api/room" api works as it gives me json data when i use it in seperate tab. My api is running in 8000 port and frontend in 3000 port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting cors origin to your react app?